# How to display multiple flashmessages in the backend of OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

Currently OctoberCMS only displays first [flash message](http://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-flash) of each type (success, error etc). There is an [issue](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2430) about it too in github.

I need to show all the messages. A very simple use case is when deleting records in a list. If some of the records are not deleted, then error messages should be shown about them and also a success message saying which ones were deleted successfully.

Can someone suggest a workaround for this issue so that multiple messages can be shown?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to swap out the native notifications functionality by overriding the defalt layout in `flash_messages.htm` with something like this (using [Noty](http://ned.im/noty/))

```
    <?php 
    $types = ['success', 'info', 'warning', 'error'];
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php 
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            foreach (Flash::$type() as $message): ?>
                new Noty({
                    type: '<?=$type?>',
                    layout: 'topCenter',
                    text: '<?= e($message) ?>',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    progressBar: false,
                    closeWith: ['click', 'button']
                }).show()
            <?php endforeach;
        }
        ?>
    </script>
```